# How to make pb.h small to reduce compile times

Tags: c++, compilation, protocol-buffers

When a proto file is large, it makes the compiling time too long (especially when I include the header in another file).

A similar question was asked few years ago, but no response: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7340

Is there a way in which this can made faster?

We use Bazel, so pre-compiled headers are not an option.

Comment: at the close request, please let me know what additional clarity is needed rather than silently voting to close.

Comment: What could possibly be an answer to this question?  Everyone wants everything to compile faster, and if there were a way to do that for something as widely used as Protocol Buffers it would be surprising if you weren’t already using it.

Comment: @DavisHerring That is what the question is about. If I knew "what could possibly be the answer" then I would not have asked the question itself. And as you can see there is already an answer, which is worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

Use forward declaration where you can. For example, if your header only needs pointers to a generated message type, you can declare:

```
class MyMessage;
```

to avoid including the whole generated header.

---

In addition, there is a [poorly documented](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/a4576cb8208ea8f1c4b05b9bb35533201e301171/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/generator.cc#L111-L113) option `proto_h` in protoc C++ backend, which should better allow forward-declaration of the messages. I do not know how it is supposed to be used, but here is what I know.

It can be invoked this way:

```
protoc --cpp_out=proto_h=true:outputdir myproto.proto
```

In addition to normal outputs `myproto.pb.h` and `myproto.pb.cc`, you will get `myproto.proto.h`. It seems that content from `.pb.h` is mostly moved to `.proto.h` as-is, with a few added forward declarations.

Comment: I will give it a try and get back, probably in a couple of days.